# Shaded rotated text in background of bookcover

Tags: backgrounds, bookcover

I have a problem with the class bookcover. I would like to add a gray shaded slightly rotated text as background. This text should be allowed to hit the paper boundaries but should be cutted of in this case. I guess most of you have seen such designs. I tried using the \rotatebox but then the text stays strictly inside the boundaries. Does anyone of you have an idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the code you have so far? Then we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: It is easier of overlay the margins than change them.  The most general solution would be to use a tikxpicture [overlay, remember picture] and {current page).  BTW, real book covers (as opposed to PDF covers) are printed on a larger size paper and cut down to size later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for the advice to use tikz-Picture. I could make it done with the following code

```
\bookcovercomponent{tikz clip}{whole}{
    \node[text width=300mm, rotate=30, anchor=center,opacity=0.3] at (50mm,50mm) {backgroundtext};}
```